# Javascript Object equivilent of JSON.stringify's replace function

Tags: javascript

Say I have an object

`const data = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: { hello: 'hello'} }`

And I'd like to run a (deep) replacer function on that, like the one supplied with `JSON.stringify`:

```
const stringData = JSON.stringify(data, (k, v) => {
    if (k === 'hello') {
     return 'hello world!';
    }
    return v;
})
//{"a":"a","b":"b","c":{"hello":"hello world!"}}
```

But without actually strigifying that object. What would be the easiest way to do so (without any external library, actual implementation of a replacement function and without stingifying-parsing)?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe write a recursive function that traverses the object graph carrying out the value modifications as necessary? Note that you'll have some of the same problems that `JSON.stringify()` has in general, because object graphs can have cycles.

Comment: @Pointy I've edited my question, this is exactly the kind of thing I'd want to avoid, I was thinking that there must be an out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: There is no out of the box solution.... Recursion is what you would need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already an answer on using a recursive function by @VasimHayat above which is correct. But since the main focus was on using a `replacer` function, the following variation can be used as well:

```js
const object = {
  a: "a",
  b: "b",
  c: "c",
  d: "d",
  h: {
    hello: "hello",
  },
};

function replacer(obj, key) {
  if (typeof key === "string" && key === "hello") {
    return "hello world";
  }

  return obj[key];
}

function traverse(obj, replacer) {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  for (const key of keys) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === "object" && obj[key].length) {
      // array
      obj[key] = replacer(obj, key);
    } else if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
      // object
      obj[key] = traverse(obj[key], replacer);
    } else {
      // primitive
      obj[key] = replacer(obj, key);
    }
  }

  return obj;
}

(() => {
  traverse(object, replacer);
  console.log("Object", object);
})();
```

Note that there are no ways of detecting cycles and if the object has cyclical references this will not work.